# PostGIS query within function not working as expected

Tags: java, postgresql, postgis

Below is my SQL query

```
select public.st_within(
          public.ST_SetSRID(
             public.ST_MakePoint(12.9135218,77.5950804),
             4326
          ),
          (public.ST_SetSRID((select boundary
                              from location
                              where id =3209901),4326)
          )
       );
```

I'm trying to fetch records which are falling under Bangalore location (12.9135218,77.5950804).

In my table I have a `geometry` object with Bangalore location.

But still it is returning false.

I'm using PostgreSQL.

[image: PostgreSQL query to get locations]

Answer (score 2):

Longitude 12.9135218 and latitude 77.5950804 mark a point near Spitzbergen, quite far from Bangalore.

Either bring warm clothing, or use the coordinates `(77.5950804,12.9135218)`.

Comment: Thank you @Laurenz AlbeIs , Is there any website I can find address by sending lat and lan ?

Comment: Thank you so much , AI have tried inter changing like below and working fine now .  **(77.5950804,12.9135218).